# Place an infoBox above all markers (google maps)

Tags: google-maps, infobox

I noticed something strange when using the infoBox extension from google. When the infoBox is shown markers that are below the infoBox can be clicked, even though they are not visible. In my case and I am guessing in most cases this is very undesirable. How do I place the infoBox 'on top' so the markers below the infoBox are not click able.

Below a little code snippets. Click the top marker. Move your mouse over the white space of the infoBox where the other markers should be. The cursor changes into a pointer and the marker is click able. BTW googles own symbols are also click able. This is also undesirable.

```js
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a){a=a||{};B.C.1E.1Z(2,2C);2.17=a.1m||"";2.1j=a.1h||16;2.14=a.1x||0;2.L=a.1q||11 B.C.1I(0,0);2.K=a.W||11 B.C.1H(0,0);2.T=a.U||F;2.1z=a.1y||{};2.1e=a.1g||"2S";2.R=a.1b||"2F://2B.B.2z/2v/2t/2q/1r.2l";4(a.1b===""){2.R=""}2.1a=a.1k||11 B.C.1I(1,1);2.V=a.1i||16;2.1F=a.25||"23";2.3=F;2.G=F;2.N=F}7.8=11 B.C.1E();7.8.1C=6(){5 a;4(!2.3){2.3=18.1Y("1X");2.1d();2.3.9.W="1W";2.3.9.S=\'1w\';4(2.T!==F){2.3.9.U=2.T}2.3.1v=2.1c()+2.17;2.2O()[2.1F].2H(2.3);2.1u();4(2.3.9.J){2.N=1t}Y{4(2.14!==0&&2.3.13>2.14){2.3.9.J=2.14;2.3.9.2w="2u";2.N=1t}Y{a=2.1M();2.3.9.J=(2.3.13-a.X-a.12)+"15";2.N=16}}2.1o(2.1j);B.C.H.Z(2,"2k")}};7.8.1c=6(){5 a="";4(2.R!==""){a="<2j";a+=" 2i=\'"+2.R+"\'";a+=" 2g=12";a+=" 9=\'";a+=" W: 2f;";a+=" 2c: 2b;";a+=" 2a: "+2.1e+";";a+="\'>"}Q a};7.8.1u=6(){5 a;4(2.R!==""){a=2.3.29;2.G=B.C.H.28(a,\'27\',2.1G())}Y{2.G=F}};7.8.1G=6(){5 a=2;Q 6(){a.1r();B.C.H.Z(a,"26")}};7.8.1o=6(A){4(!A){5 d=2.24();5 v=d.22();5 i=d.21();5 g=i.13;5 j=i.1D;5 b=v.20();5 h=b.M();5 r=b.O();5 o=h/g;5 s=r/j;5 t=v.1B().M();5 m=v.1A().M();5 e=v.1A().O();5 y=v.1B().O();5 a=2.K;5 u=2.L.J;5 w=2.L.1f;5 n=2.1a.J;5 p=2.1a.1f;5 z=a.M()+(u-n)*o;5 x=a.M()+(u+2.3.13+n)*o;5 k=a.O()-(w-p)*s;5 q=a.O()-(w+2.3.1D+p)*s;5 l=(z<t?t-z:0)+(x>m?m-x:0);5 f=(k>e?e-k:0)+(q<y?y-q:0);4(!(f===0&&l===0)){5 c=d.2R();d.2P(11 B.C.1H(c.O()-f,c.M()-l))}}};7.8.1d=6(){5 i;5 a=2.1z;2M(i 2K a){4(a.2G(i)){2.3.9[i]=a[i]}}4(E 2.3.9.1l!=="D"){2.3.9.2E="2D(1l="+(2.3.9.1l*2A)+")"}};7.8.1M=6(){5 c;5 a={19:0,1s:0,X:0,12:0};5 b=2.3;4(18.1n&&18.1n.1P){c=b.2y.1n.1P(b,"");4(c){a.19=I(c.1O,10)||0;a.1s=I(c.1N,10)||0;a.X=I(c.1L,10)||0;a.12=I(c.1Q,10)||0}}Y 4(18.2s.P){4(b.P){a.19=I(b.P.1O,10)||0;a.1s=I(b.P.1N,10)||0;a.X=I(b.P.1L,10)||0;a.12=I(b.P.1Q,10)||0}}Q a};7.8.2r=6(){4(2.3){2.3.2x.2p(2.3);2.3=F}};7.8.1p=6(){2.1C();5 a=2.2o().2n(2.K);2.3.9.X=(a.x+2.L.J)+"15";2.3.9.19=(a.y+2.L.1f)+"15";4(2.V){2.3.9.S=\'1w\'}Y{2.3.9.S="1K"}};7.8.2m=6(a){4(E a.1y!=="D"){2.1z=a.1y;2.1d()}4(E a.1m!=="D"){2.1J(a.1m)}4(E a.1h!=="D"){2.1j=a.1h}4(E a.1x!=="D"){2.14=a.1x}4(E a.1q!=="D"){2.L=a.1q}4(E a.W!=="D"){2.1V(a.W)}4(E a.U!=="D"){2.1U(a.U)}4(E a.1g!=="D"){2.1e=a.1g}4(E a.1b!=="D"){2.R=a.1b}4(E a.1k!=="D"){2.1a=a.1k}4(E a.1i!=="D"){2.V=a.1i}4(2.3){2.1p()}};7.8.1J=6(a){2.17=a;4(2.3){4(2.G){B.C.H.1S(2.G);2.G=F}4(!2.N){2.3.9.J=""}2.3.1v=2.1c()+a;4(!2.N){2.3.9.J=2.3.13+"15";2.3.1v=2.1c()+a}2.1u()}B.C.H.Z(2,"2I")};7.8.1V=6(a){2.K=a;4(2.3){2.1p()}B.C.H.Z(2,"2J")};7.8.1U=6(a){2.T=a;4(2.3){2.3.9.U=a}B.C.H.Z(2,"2h")};7.8.2L=6(){Q 2.17};7.8.1R=6(){Q 2.K};7.8.2N=6(){Q 2.T};7.8.2e=6(){2.V=16;2.3.9.S="1K"};7.8.2d=6(){2.V=1t;2.3.9.S="1w"};7.8.2Q=6(b,a){4(a){2.K=a.1R()}2.1T(b);4(2.3){2.1o()}};7.8.1r=6(){4(2.G){B.C.H.1S(2.G);2.G=F}2.1T(F)};',62,179,'||this|div_|if|var|function|InfoBox|prototype|style||||||||||||||||||||||||||||google|maps|undefined|typeof|null|closeListener_|event|parseInt|width|position_|pixelOffset_|lng|fixedWidthSet_|lat|currentStyle|return|closeBoxURL_|visibility|zIndex_|zIndex|isHidden_|position|left|else|trigger||new|right|offsetWidth|maxWidth_|px|false|content_|document|top|infoBoxClearance_|closeBoxURL|getCloseBoxImg_|setBoxStyle_|closeBoxMargin_|height|closeBoxMargin|disableAutoPan|isHidden|disableAutoPan_|infoBoxClearance|opacity|content|defaultView|panBox_|draw|pixelOffset|close|bottom|true|addClickHandler_|innerHTML|hidden|maxWidth|boxStyle|boxStyle_|getNorthEast|getSouthWest|createInfoBoxDiv_|offsetHeight|OverlayView|pane_|getCloseClickHandler_|LatLng|Size|setContent|visible|borderLeftWidth|getBoxWidths_|borderBottomWidth|borderTopWidth|getComputedStyle|borderRightWidth|getPosition|removeListener|setMap|setZIndex|setPosition|absolute|div|createElement|apply|toSpan|getDiv|getBounds|floatPane|getMap|pane|closeclick|click|addDomListener|firstChild|margin|pointer|cursor|hide|show|relative|align|zindex_changed|src|img|domready|gif|setOptions|fromLatLngToDivPixel|getProjection|removeChild|mapfiles|onRemove|documentElement|en_us|auto|intl|overflow|parentNode|ownerDocument|com|100|www|arguments|alpha|filter|http|hasOwnProperty|appendChild|content_changed|position_changed|in|getContent|for|getZIndex|getPanes|setCenter|open|getCenter|2px'.split('|'),0,{}))
var myOptions = {
             content: "aa"
            ,disableAutoPan: true
            ,maxWidth: 0
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, -5)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
    backgroundColor:"white",
               width: "280px",
    height:"110px",
    overflow:"hidden",
    zIndex:"99999",
    borderRadius:"2px",
    boxSizing:"border-box",
    MozBoxSizing:"border-box",
    webkitBoxSizing:"border-box",
    padding:"5px",
    border:"1px solid #708187",
    font:"12px verdana",
    lineHeight:"20px"

             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "2px 2px 2px 2px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(5, 1)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
        };
var ibb = new InfoBox(myOptions);
ibb.isClicked = false;
ibb.isOpen = false;

var LocationData = [
    [49.2818668, -123.1025187, "Top Marker. If this marker is clicked other markers <b>should not be clickable</b> but they are." ], 
    [49.2812668, -123.1035942, "Marker" ], 
    [49.2812336, -123.1020622, "Marker" ], 
    [49.2813564, -123.1012253, "Marker" ]
];
 
function initialize()
{
 var mapOptions = {disableDefaultUI: true}
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     
    for (var i in LocationData)
    {
        var p = LocationData[i];
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p[0], p[1]);
        bounds.extend(latlng);
         
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map,
            title: p[2]
        });


google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(mm, tt) {
    return function() {
   ibb.setContent(tt);
   ibb.open(map, mm);
   ibb.isOpen = true;
    }
})(marker, p[2]));

    }
     
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
 
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<div id="map-canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be change your infowindow's latlong position to make sure it doesn't overlap with the marker.

Comment: This is not an option. To many markers that are very close to each other.

Comment: How about hiding other markers when one infowindow is displaying and then when the user clicks outside the infowindow  the markers reappear.

Comment: Although this might work it does seem a bit overkill. There must be a function / property to place the infoBox on top of all other elements.